# Draw \ pull water from well

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

> He is **drawing** water from well.
>
> He is **pulling** water from well.

Which is more suitable in this context?
Is there any suitable phrasal verb for this?

Thank you.

Comment: The only way that *pulling* sounds natural to me is: *he is pulling* ***a bucket of*** *water from the well.*

Answer (score 1):

"Draw" is idiomatic, although this particular definition is specific to the action of physically *dragging* water from a water source, so it's only really used with something like a well.

"Pull" does not sound idiomatic to me at all, at least not in this context.  If you don't want to use "draw" then you can use "take" or "take out":

> **Take** some water from the well and bring it to the kitchen.

or various others such as "fetch", "get", "bring", "collect" etc.

> Tell your brother to go **fetch** some water from the well and bring it to the kitchen.

Note:  In a different context you can "pull water" from a source, but this implies a different sort of action, for example:

> [Scientists Pull Water Out of Thin Air](https://newscenter.lbl.gov/2017/04/13/scientists-make-water-from-air/)

In this case the scientists "pull" water by *condensing* water vapor using special materials.